# How to use a regex in Jest to search cross platform $(pwd)

Tags: node.js, jestjs, npm-scripts

```
"generate": "cross-env ROOT_PATH=$(pwd) cross-env PACT=true jest --runInBand --testEnvironment=node --testPathPattern='.*[^/]pact\\.js$'"
```

I'm trying to figure out why my `--testPathPattern` is not matching files on Windows. Jest docs say to use `/` as path separator.

I think the problem is the `ROOT_PATH` because this won't work on Windows, I also tried `./` but that's not allowing me to match either.